# Обновление DataGrid после изменения в БД

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Прошу подсказать какая хорошая практика обновления отображения данных в DataGrid после операций с БД (EntityFramework/WPF). Ранее приходилось после каждого добавления/изменения/удаления повторно запрашивать данные из БД FillViewContracts(), хотелось бы этого избежать и настроить коллекцию на определение изменений в связанной коллекции.

```
class Contract_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ViewBalanceContract selectedContract;
    //private OrganizationalStructure selectedOrgStruct;

    public ViewBalanceContract SelectedContract
    {
        get { return selectedContract; }
        set
        {
            selectedContract = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedContract");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ViewBalanceContract> ViewBalanceContracts { get; set; }

    public Contract_ViewModel()
    {
        ViewBalanceContracts = new ObservableCollection<ViewBalanceContract> (EntityConnection.FillViewContracts());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgContractView" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewBalanceContracts, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged }" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContract}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="284" Margin="406,116,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1142" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Status" Binding="{Binding StatusContract }" Header="Статус" Width="45*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NameCustomer" Binding="{Binding NameCustomer}" Header="Заказчик" Width="45*" >
....
</DataGrid>
```

Загрузка данных:

```
        internal static IEnumerable<ViewBalanceContract> FillViewContracts()
    {
        var _db = new EntityModel();
        {
            //не выдает информацию return _db.ViewBalanceContracts.Local;
            return _db.ViewBalanceContracts.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Код формы:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Contract_ViewModel();
    }
```

Comment: Коллеги, код приведен для примера, мне не нужно готовое решение, нужна помощь с выработкой правильного подхода к обновлению наборов наборов из БД. Можно ли как-то избежать запросов к БД на обновление или практика вставка/удаление/модификация записи -> запрос таблицы из БД является нормой?

Comment: Почему Contract_ViewModel имеет событие PropertyChanged, но не реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вот косяк так косяк, спасибо, поправлю

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я не понимаю как сообщить об изменении данных в БД ObservableCollection

Comment: У вас Contract_ViewModel.ViewBalanceContracts создается как копия коллекции, возвращаемой FillViewContracts, поэтому изменения в модели никак не отражаются. Надо либо привязывать напрямую к EntityModel.ViewBalanceContracts, либо как-то задействовать [CollectionView](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netcore-3.0)